# Can't get Google Maps JavaScript API to display map

Tags: google-maps

I'm having problems using Goggle Maps API.  I can't get the map to show. Below is my code, and I have styled the map div externally with a width and height.  Any suggestions?  I'm relatively new to coding, and also to StacOverflow so apologies if I'm not following etiquette!

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block title %}Profile{% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
    <script>
      function initMap()
      {
        var options = {
          zoom: 8,
          center {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbzIlcsHTVt1OqDwlLIoVXFEwphLqWQjk&callback=initMap"
      async defer></script>

    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}

        <h1>Profile</h1>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>First name</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.firstName }}</dd>

            <dt>Last Name</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lastName }}</dd>

            <dt>Latitude</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lat }}</dd>

            <dt>Longitude</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lng }}</dd>

            <dt>email</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.email }}</dd>
        </dl>

        <a href="/profile/edit">Edit</a>

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You shoudln't post your public key online

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 small issues in your code

1. A typo in the option variable in your script. there is a missing colon and an extra semicolon.
2. the CSS style is missing. (if you already have this in your base.html you may need to take the extra style tag off)

Here is the code after fixing the issues. put it in an HTML file and it should work.

```js
{% extends "base.html" %}
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

    {% block title %}Profile{% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}


    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}

        <h1>Profile</h1>

        <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap()
      {
        var options = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
        }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbzIlcsHTVt1OqDwlLIoVXFEwphLqWQjk&callback=initMap"
      async defer></script>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>First name</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.firstName }}</dd>

            <dt>Last Name</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lastName }}</dd>

            <dt>Latitude</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lat }}</dd>

            <dt>Longitude</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.lng }}</dd>

            <dt>email</dt>
            <dd>{{ user.email }}</dd>
        </dl>

        <a href="/profile/edit">Edit</a>

    {% endblock %}
```